# Search query in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having some items in database. i filter using "like" keyword

Query:`mCursor = mDb.query(listTable, new String[] { ID_rs,
                    Item_name, item_code, Unit_code, Tot_Amt, dis_count, },
                    Item_name + " like '%" + mix + "%' ORDER BY "
                            + Item_name + " ASC", null, null, null, null, null);`

Ex: values in the database
 1.SAKTHI readymix 
 2.curry Mix
 3.Mixture

my result :
 1.SAKTHI readymix 
 2.curry Mix
 3.Mixture

But i need "curry Mix, Mixture" as my output how can i get that. help me out!

Comment: What is the difference between the results you want and those you don't want?

Comment: Can it be done with "WHERE item_name = 'to' OR item_name = ' to'" Or "WHERE item_name IN ('to', ' to')" ?

Comment: @CL i need to search the starting of the string not the words in middle

Comment: change to `like '" + mix + "%'`  The % at the start means anything can be before, so just remove it.

Comment: @doomsknight i want to search the entire string it may present in first or second in the sentence.your query returns only the sentence start with mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going on your comments,

You could try using the syntax

```
Item_name + " like '" + mix + "%' OR " + Item_name + " like '% " + mix + "%'"
```

Where basically,

- the first matches ones that start with Item_name,
- the OR attaches ones that have Space followed by Item_name. Aka are a new word. (note the space after the %)

Comment: i have done this using Item_name + " like '% " + mix + "%' OR " + Item_name + " like '" + mix + "%'" Note: space after the first  %.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the easiest way would be to create a [full-text search table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) for the item names, but not all Android version have FTS enabled.

To search for values that begin with `mix`, use `LIKE`.
To search for values that have `mix` at the beginning of a word, use `GLOB` to search for a character that is not a letter in front of `mix`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ListTable
WHERE ItemName LIKE 'mix%'
   OR ItemName GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z][mM][iI][xX]*'
```

Unlike `LIKE`, `GLOB` is case sensitive, so you have to list both lower and upper case characters.

If a word can contain any non-ASCII letters, you have to add them to the `a-z` set.

Answer (score 1):

given that " @CL i need to search the starting of the string not the words in middle – APriya"

what if you try:

`Query:mCursor = mDb.query(listTable, new String[] { ID_rs, Item_name, item_code, Unit_code, Tot_Amt, dis_count, }, Item_name + " like '% " + mix + "%' ORDER BY " + Item_name + " ASC", null, null, null, null, null);`

note the space after first %, as the goal is to find only entries that begin with mix.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a where clause that uses an OR operator:

```
WHERE Item LIKE '%to' OR Item LIKE 'to%'
```